# WatiN, IE instances and grabbing them by their hWnd value

Tags: watin

I am currently using WatiN to automate a proprietary website at my work, and am running into an issue with being able to grab an IE session by its hWnd value.

As of this writing, I can start IE, handle the pop-up that occurs (the site uses JavaScript to generate certain things dynamically), but cannot return to the main IE (the first) window once I have finished interacting with the pop-up.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had trouble with this before and its because i was using local variables between postbacks to store the references to the elements.

don't do this

```
    var btn = Browser.Button("clientid")
    btn.Click(); //assume that this triggers a postback
    var result = btn.Text;
```

do this

```
    Browser.Button("clientid").Click();
    result = Browser.Button("clientid").Text;
```

Comment: Sorry about the 'unaccept', AI P.  I was trying to post on something else and got my tabs crossed-up.  I have corrected my mistake.